# How to drop rows with string <NA> value and trim strings from pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below python code:

```
import streamlit as st
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

git_output = subprocess.run(['git', 'worktree', 'list', '--porcelain'], cwd='F:/myenv/',
                            capture_output=True,
                            text=True).stdout
    
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {line.split()[0]: line.rsplit(" ", 1) for line in block.splitlines()}
    for block in git_output.split("\n\n")])
    
st.table(df.filter(items=['worktree', 'branch']))
```

and the output is:

```
    worktree                    branch
0   ["worktree","F:/demo/a"]    <NA>
1   ["worktree","F:/demo/b"]    ["branch","refs/heads/dev/demo/b"]
2   ["worktree","F:/demo/c"]    ["branch","refs/heads/dev/demo/c"]
3   <NA>                        <NA>
```

which actions I can do on the `df` object to get this output:

```
    worktree      branch
0   [F:/demo/b]   [refs/heads/dev/demo/b]
1   [F:/demo/c]   [refs/heads/dev/demo/c]
```

Per the comments, also added Dictionary value:

```
{'worktree': {0: ['worktree', 'F:/myenv'], 1: ['worktree', 'F:/demo/a'], 2: ['worktree', 'F:/demo/b'], 3: ['worktree', 'F:/demo/c'], 4: nan}, 'bare': {0: ['bare'], 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'HEAD': {0: nan, 1: ['HEAD', '48cfcf49e277bafad'], 2: ['HEAD', '21eae7bc2694a3aaaf'], 3: ['HEAD', '28755aad57bf4820ca5'], 4: nan}, 'branch': {0: nan, 1: ['branch', 'refs/heads/dev/demo/a'], 2: ['branch', 'refs/heads/dev/demo/b'], 3: ['branch', 'refs/heads/dev/demo/c'], 4: nan}, 'prunable': {0: nan, 1: ['prunable gitdir file points to non-existent', 'location'], 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

Comment: is `<NA>` a string or the nan value?

Comment: It's a string..

Comment: Then `df[df.ne('<NA>').all(1)]` will drop them.

Comment: I hope it will, but I can still see the rows with that value

Comment: You should include the output of `st.table(df.filter(items=['worktree', 'branch'])).to_dict()` to your question.

Comment: My bad, it's nan value... I added the value of `df.head().to_dict()` to the question body

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import ast
df = df.dropna().astype(str).apply(lambda col: col.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)[-1]))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    worktree                 branch
1  F:/demo/b  refs/heads/dev/demo/b
2  F:/demo/c  refs/heads/dev/demo/c
```

If you're sure that the contain real `list` objects and not just strings, you can omit the `astype(str)` and `ast` stuff:

```
df = df.dropna().apply(lambda col: col.str[-1]))
```

Comment: For both `df.dropna()` it returns empty results

Comment: Will you please send the result of `print(df.head().to_dict())`?

Comment: I added the value you asked in the question body

Comment: Oh, `dropna` is dropping all the rows because the of the `bare` and `prunable` columns, which are mostly empty...

Comment: So update your sample data and your expected output to account for those columns as well.

Comment: You can pass `subset=['col1', 'col', ...]` to `dropna` which will tell it to only drop rows with nulls _in those_ columns, instead of all the columns, e.g. `.dropna(subset=['worktree', 'HEAD', 'branch'])`

Comment: Tnx, the `subset` indeed helps

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments and suggested answer this is what worked for me:

```
import streamlit as st
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import ast


git_output = subprocess.run(['git', 'worktree', 'list', '--porcelain'], cwd='F:/views/g/MonoCentral',
                            capture_output=True,
                            text=True).stdout

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {line.split()[0]: line.rsplit(" ", 1) for line in block.splitlines()}
    for block in git_output.split("\n\n")])

df_new = df.dropna(subset=['worktree', 'HEAD', 'branch'])

df_filter = df_new.filter(items=['worktree', 'branch'])

df_filter['worktree'] = df_filter['worktree'].str[1]

df_filter['branch'] = df_filter['branch'].str[1]

st.table(df_filter)
```